# Trying to get DropDown value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get Dropdown select value for my On change Function but got undefined value.

what I did so far is that

```
  <div class="list">
  <div class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
      Status
    </div>
    <select id="ddlstatus"  ng-model="status" ng-change="getalert()" >


      <option  ng-repeat=" status in Status" value="{{status.StatusCodeId}}">{{status.StatusCode}}</option>

    </select>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and my Angular Code is

```
   $scope.StatusD =function(){

  $scope.Status=[ ];
   $http({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: Baseurl+'/api/Status'
        }).then(function(resp){
        $scope.Status = resp.data;
        console.log($scope.Status);
          });
      };
   $scope.getalert=function()alert(document.getElementById("ddlstatus").value)}
```

so what I'm missing here.how can I get selected dropdown value so I can use it further

Answer (score 2):

You have bound your select's value to the `$scope.status`, so you can get the dropdowns value with `$scope.status`.

```
$scope.getalert = function() {
   alert($scope.status).
}
```

**Example**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){  
   $scope.status = 'value1';
  
   $scope.getalert = function(){
      alert($scope.status);
   };
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select id="ddlstatus"  ng-model="status" ng-change="getalert()" >
    <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
    <option value="value4">Value 4</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Suren Srapyan has loophole that the first option in select box is displayed as undefined.

[image: A console]

The below code is the solution for the same.

```js
//--app.module.js--// 
angular.module('app', []);
//--app.controller.js--//
angular.module('app')
  .controller('StatusController', StatusController);

StatusController.$inject = ['$log'];

function StatusController($log) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.status = 'value1';
  vm.showStatusConsole = showStatusConsole;

  function showStatusConsole() {
    $log.log('Current Status Is:- ' + vm.status);
  }
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<body ng-controller="StatusController as statusObj">
  <select id="ddlstatus" ng-model="statusObj.status" ng-change="statusObj.showStatusConsole()">
    <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
    <option value="value4">Value 4</option>
  </select>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.module.js"></script>
  <script src="app.controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```